# Can't delete a node using a condition in circular linked list in c

Tags: c, circular-list

I have a circular linked list as follows which keeps a status of data to be processed. The status is used to decide to delete from the list which could be at the beginning, middle or end. The list might not even have any data at all at times or might have more than one node to delete.

```
struct data
{
    bool status;
    char other_info[20];
    struct data *next;
};
```

I tried the following code

```
struct data* delete_nodes(struct data *head)
{
    struct data* first = NULL, *prev = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    first = head;
    temp = head;
    prev = head;
    do
    {
        //prev = temp;

        if (temp != NULL && temp->next == head)
        {
            head->next = NULL;
            free(temp);
            head = NULL;
            return head;
        }

        if (temp != NULL && temp->status == true)
        {
            //temp = prev;
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = prev->next;

        }
        else if(temp != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        if (temp == NULL)
            return head;
    } while (temp != NULL && first != temp);
    head = temp;
    return head;
}
```

Now, pushing data into it works fine. deleting also works fine if there is only one node. but when there are more than one node to be deleted it crashes.

The `delete_nodes()` function is invoked by a thread which processes data if there is any and invokes `delete_nodes()`

Comment: Does `delete_nodes()` remove all nodes except for the head?

Comment: it should delete any node as long as its 'status' is 'true'

Comment: Including the head if status is true, right?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block

```
    if (temp != NULL && temp->status == true)
    {
        //temp = prev;
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = prev->next;

    }
```

is for sure wrong when doing the first iteration.

At the first iteration `prev` and `temp` are both the same as `head`. So `prev` is pointing to the same memory as you are `free`-ing.

Consider to drop all the checks for `NULL` and only have a check in the start, i.e.

```
struct data* delete_nodes(struct data *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;
    // Hereafter no further checks for NULL is needed
```

A complete function could look like:

```
struct data* delete_nodes(struct data *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;

    struct data *prev = NULL;
    struct data *temp = head;
    struct data *first = head;

    do
    {
        struct data *next = temp->next;
        if (temp->status)
        {
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                // Delete head element
                head = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                // Delete middle element
                prev->next = temp->next;
            }
            free(temp);
        } 
        else 
        {
            prev = temp;
        }
        temp = next;
    } while (temp != first);

    if (prev == NULL)
    {
         // List is empty
         return NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I have a related question to the one you answered here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623528/circular-linked-list-not-working-properly-in-c-windows). Can you have a look at it please.

Answer (score 0):

Below statement is causing the problem

```
prev->next = temp->next; // what is prev here ?
```

It should be

```
if (temp != NULL && temp->next !=NULL && temp->status == true) {
        prev = temp;//current node which you want to delete 
        temp->next = prev->next;//this statement should be done before next statement..current node next should be prev node next
        prev->next = temp->next;//
        free(temp);
        temp = prev->next;
  }
```