# circular linked list not working properly in c windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, circular-list

I tried to implement circular linked list to manage a set of tasks by a server side application. The application is multi-threaded where one thread (**`updater()`** ) reads the linked list only for read while another two (**`push_stream() and delete_stream()`**) access the linked list to add to and delete from the linked list respectively.

My problem is not all the files to be deleted (after being processed) are deleted.

```
 struct data_stream
{
    bool processed;
    int count;
    char filename[30];
    int TYPE_GRP;
    int task_type;
    struct data_stream *next;
};

struct data_stream *stream_head=NULL; //global variable
```

main(partial code)

```
main()
{

_beginthread(updater, 0, NULL);

while ((new_socket = accept(srv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, handle_client, &new_socket, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

handle_client function (partial code)

```
 handle_client()
    {

//some where in handle_client    
    EnterCriticalSection(&stream_lock);
    stream_head = push_stream(&stream_head, TYPE_GRP, task_type);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&stream_lock);

    }
```

updater function (full source code)

```
void updater(void *data)
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct data_stream*temp = stream_head;
        struct data_stream*first = stream_head;
        struct data_stream*prev = NULL;
        if (stream_head != NULL)
        {
            struct data_stream*next = NULL;
            do
            {
                next = temp->next;
                if (temp->processed == false&&temp->task_type == 2)
                {
                   process_files(temp); 
                }
                else if (temp->processed == false&&temp->task_type == 3)
                    {
                    process_others();
                    }
                EnterCriticalSection(&stream_lock);
                temp->processed = true;
                LeaveCriticalSection(&stream_lock);
                temp = next;

            } while (temp != first);
        }
        if (stream_head != NULL)
        {
            EnterCriticalSection(&stream_lock);
            stream_head=delete_stream(&stream_head);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&stream_lock);
        }
        Sleep(6000);
    }
}
```

process_files

```
void process_files(struct data_stream*temp)
{
    int count = 0;
    char file_to_update[50] = { NULL };
    size_t name_len = strlen(temp->filename);
    memcpy_s(file_to_update, name_len, temp->filename, name_len);
    file_to_update[name_len] = '\0';
    temp->count = 0;
    FILE *list_to_update ;
    fopen_s(&list_to_update , file_to_update, "r+b");
    if (list_to_update != NULL)
        {
            char readline[100] = { '\0' };
            while (fgets(readline, sizeof(readline), list_to_update ) != NULL)              
                {
                    //read a line at a time and process the list
                    count++;
                }
            temp->count = count;
            fclose(list_to_update );
        }
        else
            printf("\nerror opening file\n");
}
```

process_others()

```
void process_others(struct data_stream*temp)
 {
    int count = 0;
    char file_to_update[50] = { NULL };
    size_t name_len = strlen(temp->filename);
    memcpy_s(file_to_update, name_len, temp->filename, name_len);
    file_to_update[name_len] = '\0';
    temp->count = 0;
    FILE *list_to_update ;
    fopen_s(&list_to_update , file_to_update, "r+b");
     if (list_to_update != NULL)
        {
            char readline[100] = { '\0' };
            while (fgets(readline, sizeof(readline), list_to_update ) != NULL)              
               {
                    //read a line at a time and process the list
                    count++;
                }
            temp->count = count;
            fclose(list_to_update );
        }
        else
         {
            printf("\nerror opening file\n");
        }
    }

}
```

push_stream (full source code)

```
struct data_stream* push_stream(struct data_data_stream**head_ref, int typ_grp, int task_type)
{
    struct data_stream*new_data_stream=
        (struct data_data_stream*)malloc(sizeof(struct data_stream));
    new_stream->processed = false;
    new_stream->task_type = task_type;
    new_stream->TYPE_GRP = typ_grp;
    new_stream->filename[0] = NULL;
    new_stream->count = 0;
    new_stream->next = NULL;
    if (task_type == 2)
        sprintf_s(new_stream->filename, "%s%03d.txt", "file_md5_list_", stream_count);
    else
        sprintf_s(new_stream->filename, "%s%03d.txt", "other_list_", stream_count);
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_stream;
        new_stream->next = new_stream;
    }
    else
    {
        struct data_stream* last = (*head_ref)->next;
        struct data_stream* prev = (*head_ref)->next;
        while (last != *head_ref)
        {   
            prev = last;
            last = last->next;          
        }   
        new_stream->next = *head_ref;
        last->next = new_stream;
    }
    if (stream_count > 998)
        stream_count = 1;
    else
        stream_count++;
    return new_stream;
}
```

delete_stream function (full source code)

```
struct data_stream* delete_stream(struct data_data_stream**head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;    
    struct data_stream*prev = NULL;
    struct data_stream*temp = *head;
    struct data_stream*first = *head;
    do
    {
        struct data_stream*next = temp->next;
        if (temp->processed)
        {
            if (prev == NULL)
                *head = temp->next;
            else
                prev->next = temp->next;

            char file_to_delete[50] = { NULL };
            memcpy_s(file_to_delete, strlen(temp->filename), temp->filename, strlen(temp->filename));
            DeleteFileA(file_to_delete);
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            prev = temp;
        }
        temp = next;
    } while (temp != first);
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return *head;
}
```

Comment: You say *on windows* and I think, it sure "*works*" on other OS, so **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**. Also, avoid writing code like `updater()`, if you split that in reasonable blocks of code that do a single thing and do it well, the bug might magically disappear. I wont even bother reading that code, it's too *difficult*. More than 3 levels of indentation make the code difficult, and is almost never needed, you have about 6 levels, I didn't count.

Comment: It's actually not crazy to write code like `while (condition) do_single_thing();` and so on, because then it's extremely clear what the code is doing. And a final comment and I'll get back to work, use a debugger.

Comment: I have not tried it on other OSs. I am a beginner, and am learning through my mistakes.

Comment: I understand that, that's why I am giving you advice. Try and split the `updater()` function in several functions, each doing a single thing. And then check if the code works again. That way not only you have way less chance of doing it wrong. That way also, you will be able to debug the code much easier. Sorry if you fell that I am being rude, I didn't mean to.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Sorry about my comment above. English is not my first language and it seems I have sent the wrong message there. I take your advice in its full sense.

Comment: I think you need this change: `last->next = new_stream;` -> `prev->next = new_stream;`

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I have split the **'updater()'** function. I hope it is more readable now.

Comment: It's not clear to me how many threads you have. Your description suggests 3 threads, i.e. a thread for `updater()`, a thread for `push_stream()` and a thread for `delete_stream()`. But looking at the code it shows that `updater` calls `delete_stream()`. Please clarify - how many threads do you have?

Comment: All accesses to `stream_head` shall be protected - including when you read its value